# Create multiple text files

Tags: file, delphi, application-start

what would be a neat way to create multiple *.txt files on application
startup i.e check if they exist if not create them.
I need to create about 10 text files.
Will I have to do like this for every single file:

```
var
  MyFile: textfile;
  ApplicationPath: string;
begin
  ApplicationPath := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
  if not FileExists(ApplicationPath + '\a1.txt') then
    begin
      AssignFile(MyFile, (ApplicationPath + '\a1.txt'));
      Rewrite(MyFile);
      Close(MyFile);
    end
  else 
    Abort;
end;
```

Comment: You don't mention your Delphi version. If you are on D2009+, you are advised (by Delphi) to use streams instead of the "old" Pascal file methods as these do not support Unicode.

Comment: Instead of streams, you could use `FileCreate()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
var
    ApplicationDir: string;
    I: Integer;
    F: TextFile;
begin
    ApplicationDir := ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
    for I := 1 to 10 do
      begin
        Path := ApplicationDir + '\a' + IntToStr(I) + '.txt';
        if not FileExists(Path) then
          begin
            AssignFile(F, Path);
            Rewrite(F);
            Close(F);
          end
      end;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to create the empty files (or rewrite the existing) with subsequently numbered file names, you might try something like this. The following examples use the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function. But pay attention that several things may forbid your file creation attempts!

If you want to create (overwrite) them in all circumstances, use CREATE_ALWAYS disposition flag

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Name: string;
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
  for I := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      Name := Path + 'a' + IntToStr(I) + '.txt';
      CloseHandle(CreateFile(PChar(Name), 0, 0, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0));
    end;
end;
```

Or if you want to create the files only if they doesn't exist, use the CREATE_NEW disposition flag

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  Name: string;
  Path: string;
begin
  Path := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
  for I := 1 to 10 do
    begin
      Name := Path + 'a' + IntToStr(I) + '.txt';
      CloseHandle(CreateFile(PChar(Name), 0, 0, nil, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0));
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  procedure CreateFile(Directory: string; FileName: string; Text: string);
  var
    F: TextFile;
  begin
    try
      AssignFile(F, Directory + '\' + FileName);
      {$i-}
      Rewrite(F);
      {$i+}
      if IOResult = 0 then
      begin
         Writeln(F, Text);
      end;
    finally
      CloseFile(f);
    end;
  end;
  ...

  for i := 0 to 10 do
    CreateFile(Directory, Filename, Text);
```